# Control 12V power with 3 transitors to 3 seperate consumers

Tags: arduino-uno, resistor, transistor

I have this shematic. With one electrical Pump and two solenoid valves I want to control via the arduino.

Here are the specs for the parts:

- **Pump:** 12V max. 250mA
- **Valve 1:** 12V max. 160mA
- **Valve 2:** 12V max 220mA
- **Source:** 12V max 2A

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZEVZO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My questions is:

Are the 4.7k resistors enough?
Do I need different resistors for the different consumers?
And I am using S8050 as transistors. Are they to small for the load?
And where do I have to connect the ground of the arduino to?

Comment: I think you mean S8050 as transistors and in the circuit I see 2N3904's

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: Connect the Arduino Gnd to the 12V supply Gnd.  From what I see here, https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bipolar-bjt-single/276?k=S8050 most S8050 parts need 80mA or more to turn into saturation - which is more than an Arduino can supply.  You'd be better off with N-Channel MOSFET, which takes little drive current, and with low Rds will have little voltage across the  Drain-Source. 
Example: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?k=aod5

Comment: (5v/4700r) * 100hfe = 0.106A; not enough current for any of them. Try a 330R: good for 1.5A (or still 600ma at the worst-case 40hfe), while only pulling 15ma from the MCU. You can go up to 680r...